# Removing the menu table from the login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my master page i've added an table menu that I Want to hide from from the log in page...
This is my _layout.cshtml file..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>

<body>
    <header class="feature" style="background-color: #0c1d29;">
        <div class="content-wrapper">

                <p>

                    <img src="~/Images/images.jpg" width="300" height="100"/>

                </p>
            <div class="float-right">
                <section id="login">
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                </section>
            </div>

            <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #7ac0da">Office Service Management   System</h1>
            @*<div class="float-right">

                <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">

                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>*@
        </div>

    </header>
    <div id="body">
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h3> @Html.ActionLink("User Management", "Index", "UserManagement")</h3>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h3>@Html.ActionLink("Airtel Management", "")</h3>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h3> @Html.ActionLink("Sanketh Management", "")</h3>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h3> @Html.ActionLink("Lionel Management", "")</h3>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h3> @Html.ActionLink("Reports", "")</h3>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @*<section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">*@
                                    @RenderBody()
                                    @*</section>*@
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>

                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>

    </div>

        <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - CCI Valves Pvt Ltd.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

this is my login page.
       @model CCIOfficeServiceManagementSystem.Models.LoginModel

```
   @{
  ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/IndexPage")

 <section id="loginForm">
 <h2>Admin Login.</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm( "Login","Account",new {ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) 
 {
<span style="color:red">
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true,"Incorrect Password!!!!")
</span>

<fieldset >
    <legend>Log in Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
</fieldset>
 }
  </section>
  <aside>
<img src="~/Images/download%20(2).jpg" />
 </aside>
 @section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Request.Path to check the current page, if user is on login page then menu will not come.see below example.

```
@if (!Request.Path.ToString().Equals("/Account/login"))
    <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <h3> @Html.ActionLink("User Management", "Index", "UserManagement")</h3>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <h3>@Html.ActionLink("Airtel Management", "")</h3>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <h3> @Html.ActionLink("Sanketh Management", "")</h3>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <h3> @Html.ActionLink("Lionel Management", "")</h3>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <h3> @Html.ActionLink("Reports", "")</h3>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>

}
```

Comment: after using the above code the table menu is hidden for whole project

Comment: Yes it will be visible only when user is logged in.

Comment: @user3273883 check the updated solution it think it is what you need.

Comment: check your path and use accordingly because it is working at my end.
Request.Path.ToString().Equals("<your relative path>") path should be correct in this

Comment: I've given the correct path as you mentioned but it is redirecting to the same page..

Comment: Can you show the page url and what you are passing in request.path?

Comment: And whats your login page url ?(eg. localhost:5454/Account/login)

Comment: before it was //localhost:63035/Account/Login

Comment: @if (!Request.Path.ToString().Equals("/Account/LogOn")) this is condition i am using and my page url is http://localhost:49407/Account/LogOn

Comment: @if(!Request.Path.ToString().Equals("/Account/Login")) this is my condition and the page url is localhost:63035/Account/Login..

Comment: I am really clueless why it is not working now last option is just to debug your Request parameter

Comment: actually i'm not using the existing dbcontext class which uses the defaultconnection for authentication..

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can assign the `id of the menu` and hide on runtime using `JQuery` otherwise I will suggest to create one other layout for without authenticate users. Assign that one to login page.

Comment: No, You need to create a separate layout page and add login page into this

Comment: sorry i didn't got what you said... Can u elaborate??